# neural net width, depth

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Judging by answers to questions related to width,depth of neural nets, selecting values is more an art than science. Nets are even built that build their own layer sizes on-the fly to avoid making choices.
Why?

Factors would be: input data width, output data width. Add complexity: each I and O would have disallowed states not possible with real world data sets. Usually very finite input and output data set sizes, though all real possibilites may not always be intuitive.

Couldn't a neural net be constructed to recommend more ideal layer widths and depths than just making guesses? This would seem to be a natural in an AI researcher's tools box.

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw) help?

Comment: Seen it. No, not really, and doesn't address my question.

Comment: Done. Easier just to do it myself. Interesting results.